# How to run SSIS package without SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio, ssis

On [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977190) 2nd workaround method suggests to try running SSIS package on computer that doesn't have SQL instance. How is that possible? Do I need to have installed VS 2008 Business Intelligence or it's possible even without it?

Comment: Is your package crashing due to low memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link that may help you. Read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx).

This article has answers for your questions:

1. "You can install SQL Server Integration Services on a computer that has no previous instances of SQL Server."
2. "The Business Intelligence Development Tools (BIDS) option installs the Integration Services components required to design a package, but the Integration Services service is not installed and you cannot run packages outside of BI Development Studio."

Of couse the only install the latter is not enough to run arbitary packages.

Answer (score 1):

The following may help you:

1. Install dtexec utility on the webserver or wherever your SSIS package resides. Regarding the minimum requirements please check this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx
2. Create a .cmd/bat file that calls dtexec including all the needed parameters. Your webpage 's button or a scheduled job will trigger this .cmd or .bat file
3. Now, to stop a package in this setup, you can use a precedence constraint for example a file, you can check if the file exists before executing each next step in your SSIS package, this approach is discussed here: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/250123-Stop-SSIS-package-at-runtime.aspx. By the way to stop the package I thus suggest creating a second button.

Answer (score 0):

You can install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) without installing SQL Server by itself, and then you can use integration services.  Try this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017