# importing .mdb file using dtsx package running functionality Conversion from SQL Server into PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, etl

I am using SQL Server dtsx packages to convert the .mdb file into loaded table for importing database data. Here I am going to change my database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

So my confusion here that when I am using PostgreSQL database. Is there any alternative service that resides in PostgreSQL that corresponds to this dtsx package running and .mdb files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OLEDB Destination to connect to SQL Server, you only have to install the [OLEDB Provider for Postgres](https://www.pgoledb.com/) and change the provider from the OLEDB Connection manager. *(Or create a new connection manager)*

The following article contains a step by step guide to connect to a Postgres database using SSIS:

- [Export data from Postgres to SQL Server using SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/)

Or you can use [ODBC driver and ODBC connection manager to connect to Postgres](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)

- [SSIS WITH POSTGRESQL : CONNECT TO POSTGRESQL WITH SSIS COMPONENTS](https://mask-me.net/datamaskingwiki/wiki/168/ssis-with-postgresql-connect-to-postgresql-with-ssis-components)

SSIS is not related to Postgres, so there is no related services that you need to install. **Dtsx packages requires that SQL Server Integration Services are installed even if you don't need to import data into SQL.**

---

### Additional Information:

- [Is there a SSIS-like feature in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966474/is-there-a-ssis-like-feature-in-postgresql/27152365)
- [How to run SSIS package without SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431124/how-to-run-ssis-package-without-sql-server)
- [Can we install only SSIS on a machine without installing actual SQL Service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f9de6fce-19cc-43b1-93de-c8f2c4e856e2/can-we-install-only-ssis-on-a-machine-without-installing-actual-sql-service?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Can SSIS be installed without SQL Server?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/can-ssis-be-installed-without-sql-server)